# React Native: TouchableOpacity onPress not triggering on when absolutely positioned with zIndex

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and I'm struggling to get a `TouchableOpacity` to trigger it's press function when the element has the following CSS:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
```

Below is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const StyledImage = styled.Image`
  height: 24px;
  width: 32px;
`;

const MenuContainer = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: ${Dimensions.get('screen').height};
  width: ${Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.75};
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -16px;
`;

const ProfileSectionContainer = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
`;

const HeadingContainer = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const CloseButton = styled(Body1)`
  font-size: 18px;
`;

const MenuItemsContainer = styled.View`
  padding: 0 20px;
`;

const SignOutContainer = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100;
  flex: 1;
  left: 40%;
`;

const handleLogout = navigate => async () => {
  await logout()
  redirectToLogin(navigate)();
};

const toggleIsOpen = (isOpen, setIsOpen) => () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

const Menu = ({ isOpen, setIsOpen, navigate }) => (
  <MenuContainer>
    <HeadingContainer>
      <View>
        <Body1 color="#fff">New App</Body1>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleIsOpen(isOpen, setIsOpen)}>
          <CloseButton color="#fff">X</CloseButton>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </HeadingContainer>
    <ProfileSectionContainer>
      <ProfileSection />
    </ProfileSectionContainer>
    <MenuItemsContainer>
      <MenuItems menuItems={[{ text: 'Link 1' }, { text: 'Link 2' }]} />
    </MenuItemsContainer>
    <SignOutContainer>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogout(navigate)}>
        <Body1 color="#fff">Sign Out</Body1>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SignOutContainer>
  </MenuContainer>
);
```

I've looked at all the StackOverflow links and none of the solutions seem to work.

I'm currently on React Native `0.59.8` which is the latest at the time of writing this question.

EDIT:
The `TouchableOpacity` that currently isn't working is the `Sign Out` button which is located at the bottom of the `MenuContainer`. I do have another `TouchableOpacity` which contains the `X` to close the menu and that seems to work well.

Comment: `zIndex` camel case

Comment: I'm using `styled-components` so the `z-index` property needs to be specified in the same way that it is in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add z index on TouchableOpacity? Maybe your button its behind the others components

Comment: I've tried adding the `z-index` on the `TouchableOpacity` but it doesn't seem to work. Oddly enough, if I remove the `position: absolute` on the `MenuContainer` the entire screen layout gets messed up but the button works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bind option:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleIsOpen = this.toggleIsOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
}
```